# I've been hooked. What can I do?

Tags: overwatch

It's always a situation like this.  I'll be strolling along having a perfectly nice day decimating waves of heroes, and this scumbag Roadhog pops around a corner out of nowhere, hooks me in, then destroys me with his Scrap Gun.

It's frustrating. Whether I'm patrolling the friendly skies with Pharah or sprinting around as Soldier 76, or blinking around as Tracer, one of the few things that frustrate me to all hell is Roadhog's Hook.

Is there any ability in game that can react fast enough to a hook to mitigate the damage that comes afterward? How much time to react do I have before to avoid the face-on damage? Is there a distance visually that I am safe from his wrath, or can he catch me and almost any angle and any range (which really does seem like it when you get caught out of the sky). Is my only chance at escaping a hook bunny hopping madly like an insane rabbit? Or are there other ways to deal with this mess?

Comment: Genji´s Reflec or Mei´s Ice Block may be fast enough to be activated but i think the hook stuns you until you reach Roadhog. Can´t test it though.

Comment: @MartinH. Do you know what happens if a Genji successfully deflects a Hook attempt? Does it just hook the Roadhog to the Genji? It's kinda weird isn't it

Comment: @O-O I meant to  reflect the shot after the hook, not the hook itself. Would have to test it but can´t do that right now. But i now have a Picture of a flying Roadhog in my head :-D.

Comment: @O-O I've read that it reflects at the same angle it hit you at, so in theory you could deflect it back to another enemy and Roadhog would Hook his own team mate. In theory.

Comment: @O-O it doesnt bring hte roadhog to you, just defelcts the hook and little damage it does. I am not sure if you can deflect it to someone else, ive never "seen" the hook go in a different direction, even when deflected, but the damage might.

Comment: A Roadhog who hook Lucio is a disappointed Roadhog, who eats a RB to the face and watches his would be prey skate away. He'll be going hungry tonight.

Comment: You can "Die..Die....Die!!!"

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The following are all things that I've seen work for me and my teammates, playing from early in the closed beta to now.

Reinhardt's shield and Winston's bubble both block the hook, so if they can be raised before the hook hits anyone, that can save not only the player, but also their teammates.

As one of the other answers has said, using a character that has an "out," like a dash, you can semi-reliably escape from the Roadhog.

Dashing with Tracer or Genji, or using Tracer's Rewind, might save you if the Roadhog isn't fast enough. Likewise with Pharah's Jump Jet. McCree can try and stun the Roadhog and roll away, which might work in his favor.

Reaper and Mei can easily use their invulnerability abilities to help prevent their demise. Unfortunately, Mei's leaves her right there next to the Roadhog, so you have to hope your team can save you. Zarya's barriers both block the hook, if applied before it lands. Also, Zarya can activate a barrier on herself or an ally *after* they've been hooked to hopefully ensure the Roadhog does not get a kill, and instead gives her a big boost of energy. Call out to a Zarya on your team if you have one, and they might keep you alive.

Winston and Zenyatta can pop their Ultimate to pretty much ensure they survive the encounter, but that's probably a wasted ult.

Lastly, one thing that works for me about half the time, since I play Lucio very frequently, is to use a knockback ability (Lucio's alt-fire) on the Roadhog, which sometimes prevents a killing blow from landing and occasionally disorients the Roadhog. This can also work for Junkrat and his concussive mine. Press shift and right-click immediately. The Junkrat will be blown back, and the Roadhog might even die. If Pharah's Jump Jet is on cooldown, her Concussive Blast would knock both characters away from each other, and might be more effective than Lucio's alt-fire.

One important note with using knockback abilities: Junkrat's and Pharah's abilities move both players, so they usually work a little better in certain situations. If the Roadhog hooks you as Lucio while standing backed up against a wall, trying to blast him away with your alt-fire will be much less effective, if not pointless.

Something that *could* work against a very slow or just bad Roadhog is Hanzo's scatter shot, fired at the Roadhog's/Hanzo's feet. I've never seen this successfully done, but theoretically it *might* work.

One final note: Widowmaker's grapple probably wouldn't work, as it is very slow, but poisoning the Roadhog with a venom mine as you die might ensure that he goes down, too.

Comment: Widow Mines only do 75 damage, and Roadhog can self heal for 300, so it's very much a last ditch effort.

Comment: McCree is also solid, bam flashbang, fan the hammer for free damage, ROLL OUT

Comment: Note that there's a period of stun **as** you get reeled in, so for any ability you use to escape *after* being hooked (other than a Zarya saving you) and it's usually a long enough duration for him to get at least one scatter shot off on you.   So you either have to hope his aim is bad, or survive the initial shot.  It helps to 'land' your mitigation if you're holding the button for it while getting hooked, so that it instantly triggers when the stun wears off.

Answer (score 6):

Normally, you will die. Except if...

Factors outside of your control:

- Roadhog's competence. One that is completely new at the game might not shoot you in time, giving you enough leeway to use a defensive ability.
- Roadhog's lag.
- An ally saved you: you have an armor pack, zarya bubble, a mei wall, another hook, etc disrupting the roadhog combo.

Factor partially in your control:

- There is a bug with fast moving characters that will sometimes have you hooked behind or to the side of the Roadhog. If you are genji, tracer, or lucio, this seems to happen more often if you are moving around very quickly.

Answer (score 4):

There is no skill that makes you escape from a Roadhog hook. He can shoot mid-hook, and therefore will hit you with his shotgun while you are still stunned. Some Roadhogs don't utilize this, and one tip is to hold the "escape" (Mei Cryo-Freeze, Tracer's Recall, etc.) button down, instead of smashing it 10 times a second. Like this, the skill will activate as soon as it can be activated.

You can deal with Roadhog by staying at long range. Due to his big model, he is easy to hit, even at long range. If you can't stay at long range, stay behind your tanks. If you play a fast character like Tracer, you can kite him around or bait out the hook.

tl;dr: Avoid getting hooked. Once Roadhog hits you, you're dead.

Comment: @DCShannon Yes, I mean long range. Thank you again :D I edited my answer

Comment: One more question. To which action is the escape key bound? We console players have no escape key, and even other PC players may have remapped it.

Comment: @DCShannon by "escape key" I mean the key which is bound to any "escape" skill. For example, Tracer has her back-in-time skill (dunno how it's called) which would be "E" on default for PC players.

Comment: You might consider reword to "escape ability key" to avoid confusion with the Escape key on a PC.

Answer (score 3):

As Tracer, Genji, and other heroes with dashes, you can dash as soon as the pull duration is over, and jump to safety out of range of Roadhog's devastating gun. The heroes I have done this with are Tracer, Genji, Mcree, and Widowmaker.

Alternatively using Mei's ability where she turns to ice, or Reaper's ability to phase out, you can avoid getting hit by a shotgun blast if you react fast enough. Although this only really delays the inevitable as Mei, unless you team can get there fast enough.

Zarya is also a good pick, as you can shield yourself after you get hooked, and absorb the damage from Roadhog's gun. The main thing to succeed in countering him with any of these abilities is having quick reactions so you can use the ability before he shoots you and you die.

**Note:** None of these guarantee that you will live, however if the Roadhog miss-times his combo, you will have a better chance of surviving if you attempt to dash/shield/go untargetable as soon as the hooks disable wears off.

Comment: The only one I disagree with is widowmaker. While you could escape with the grapple, the grapple first has to travel before you start moving away and by then you would already be dead. It isn't as instant as the other moves mentioned.

Comment: Pharah ... she can rocket away in no time.

Comment: First of all note: roadhog can decide himself when to shoot you. so well timed they wil jsut give you a shot an isntant before you are released. here ie. meis iceblock would even be counter productive, since this gives roadhog the chance to prepare a second close range shot which will be a pretty clear finisher. Also you didn't mention the best protection at all. Be companioned by a Reinhard! his shield blocks of the hook as soon getting in touch with it without hooking anything.

Comment: The problem with this is, based on my own experience, it's entirely possible to be killed by Roadhog before you can use any of those abilities. There appears to be some variance in how long you're incapacitated after a hook.

Comment: A quick knockback as Lucio after getting hooked sometimes will give you enough distance that his shot will mostly miss.

Comment: @Zaibis the question clearly asks what to do after you've been hooked, so saying that you should stand next to a Reinhardt to not get hooked doesn't really help, and I touched on the fact that you will still likely die after using iceblock as Mei if your team doesn't get to you in time to help you.

Comment: @VanBuzzKill while it isnt as instant as the other abilities, it can still work. I've done it once, and seen videos of others doing it. I believe one was posted somewhere in the Overwatch chat room.

Comment: @Dragonrage: But in that case talking about your own timing isn't correct either. In that case the only real answer to OP is "After you got hooked, the only thing you can do is hooping for surrive, untill you are released again and then going on with your usual stuff." And for that I got to down vote OP now.

Comment: @Zaibis your own timing is important in regards to the fact that for the highest chance of survival, you should use your escape as soon as you are able to.

Comment: @Dragonrage: yeah but therefor you don't need to time anything but spam the escape skill's key.

Comment: @Zaibis With Mei's ice block you can cancel early to surprise the Roadhog and quickly place an ice wall giving you an escape.

Comment: I want to see you doing that while he has killed you before even leaving his stun